# Can I format my JavaScript/JQuery code with linebreaks and tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, jslint

As a c# coder learning JavaScript I find this alot more readable:

```
$(this)
  .first()
  .prepend("<h3>Title</h3>")
  .end()
  .removeClass("hidden");
```

than this:

```
$(this).first().prepend("<h3>Title</h3>").end().removeClass("hidden");
```

However JSLint complains about the first one. But I don´t understand why. Will this get me into trouble anywhere?

**Update:**
You can set the value of indentation at the bottom of the jslint page and thereby make your code "valid". There is a fork of JsLint, http://www.jshint.com/, that accepts tabs as well.

Comment: The **why** is the whitespace between the previous element and the dot

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `$(this).first()`? If `this` is an element, `$(this)` contains only of one element anyway.

Comment: I commonly write my code like the top example to make it easier to read and i have never had any problems :)

Comment: Looking at the answers I'm probably wrong about this but wouldn't javascript's automatic semicolon insertion insert a semicolon at the end of `$(this)` thereby making the rest of the code a syntax error?

Comment: there is no syntax error. Problem is like stated above itentifier<SPACE=PROBLEM>.nextIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning from JSLint is a matter of taste. Whoever wrote it finds that arranging things this way makes more sense:

```
$(this).
  first().
  prepend("<h3>Title</h3>").
  end().
  removeClass("hidden");
```

I for one find your approach more clear because the dot tells me that whatever comes after it belongs to the line above.

You're safe with the way you are writing, but I would really like to see someone (jslint devs) tell us how to disable that message.

Comment: At the bottom of the jslint page you can at least set how many spaces of indentation is allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I read the other answers. It's nice to know but I use tabs. I managed to locate this particular error in the source of jslint, but was unable to disable it. Perhaps I should make a feature request about this, because it's really none of their business how I indent my lines. After all, it's not python! Am I wrong?

Comment: Besides, I use the binary jslint and the errors appear in my text editor.

Comment: Checkout http://www.jshint.com/ it´s a fork of JSLint and it doesn't mind my tabs.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with that code on jsLint is due to the identation: if you indent it with 4 spaces there're no errors

(scroll down to the options and change identation settings if default value is not what you want)

Comment: look at the bottom of the jslint page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine if you format it like this jslint shouldn't complain (Well, of course it complains about `$` not being defined but the rest of the code is ok)

```
$(this).
    first().
    prepend("<h3>Title</h3>").
    end().
    removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

A good coding practice is that keep your code readable by you and anyone else and that is an example

```
$(this).first()
.prepend("<h3>Title</h3>")
.end()
.removeClass("hidden");

if(something)
{
   // do something
}
else
{
   //do something else
}
```

You should always use indent and it's a good coding practice.